# Bootstrap 3 - list group elements issue: excess p tags

Tags: html, css, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap, html-lists

Got a strange problem whereby the HMTL markup is being rendered differently compared to my input.
I'm using Twitter Bootstrap 3 & WordPress 3.9.2, and Chrome as a browser (latest version).

My HTML:

```
<div class="list-group">
  <a href="#" class="list-group-item active">
    <h4 class="list-group-item-heading">Important</h4>
  </a>
  <a href="#" class="list-group-item">
    <h4 class="list-group-item-heading">Heading 1</h4>
    <p class="list-group-item-text">Text for this area can go here</p>
  </a>
</div>
```

This is exactly as documented on Twitter Bootrap's documentation website:
http://getbootstrap.com/components/#list-group-custom-content

But for some strange reason, when I load the page my HTML turns into:

```
<div class="list-group">
  <a href="#" class="list-group-item active">
    <p></p>
    <h4 class="list-group-item-heading">Important</h4>
  </a>
  <p>
    <a href="#" class="list-group-item active"></a>
    <br>
    <a href="#" class="list-group-item"></a>
  </p>
  <a href="#" class="list-group-item">
    <h4 class="list-group-item-heading">Heading 1</h4>
    <p class="list-group-item-text">Text for this area can go here</p>
  </a>
  <p>
    <a href="#" class="list-group-item"></a>
  </p>
</div>
```

As you can see, it's adding extra a, p, and br tags - and duplicating some classes too.
I have even minified my input HTML to have no spaces between tags, but still this occurs.
I've also tried disabling JavaScript in the browser.

A picture of the result is here:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/rMPot.png
https://i.stack.imgur.com/8ntCR.png

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: where are you adding this code? in the wysiwyg editor? have you selected the "Text" tab in the editor?

Comment: yes - in the wysiwig editor.

Answer (score 1):

So I found out what was the culprit. WordPress (by default) was adding in extra tags, even though the WYSIWYG editor shows otherwise. Strange that this occurs in some occasions & not others.

The solution?
Insert this snippet into your functions.php file:

```
<?php remove_filter ('the_content', 'wpautop'); ?>
```

This will stop the extra tags from being unwelcomely generated